# a way to use jdbc like statement with property in soap ui

Tags: jdbc, soapui, ready-api

I've been struggling with this issue for some time now but I found some workarounds, but now I need it and can't really find a good answer for me.

I need to use in a jDBC query in ready api the '`like`' statement and with all combos I could think of or find I always end up in an error.

So use

```
select * from database where service like 'CLI%'
```

The problem might be that I use a property in this query so it's

```
select * from database where service like :ser%
```

(I've tried * and ? , and even '%' without success)

Any ideas or hints ?

Comment: Which database are you using and what's the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on a PostgreSQL database:

```
select *
from product.product
where productcode like 'P%'
```

You can even use a property:

```
select *
from product.product
where productcode like '${#TestCase#productName}%'
```